# If an Excel workbook was created in another language, would that cause characters to change when I open it on a computer that defaults to English?

Tags: microsoft-excel, language

Basically, I am working on a school project and I have a database that was created by a non-profit that was not based in the USA; I have reason to believe that this database was created either in a former Yugoslav Country or a former USSR Satellite. Regardless of where it was made, I am potentially looking at a country of origin where there are multiple official languages and depending on the language, it may use the Latin alphabet, Cyrillic alphabet, or something else entirely.

**So my issue** is that there are a lot of really strange characters appearing in the database (ex. Fractions such as ASCII code 171 (½) appearing mid sentence).

For example, one of the cells that is supposed to contain a name of a city instead says, "DÅ¾enan" and my understanding is that "Å" is not commonly used outside of Scandinavian languages (which this database should not be in).

I have reached out to the non-profit who provided us the database to try and figure out what is happening but I would like to be able to work on this today and a response from them is unlikely given their workday already ended.

**Main Question:** Would an Excel sheet that was made on an OS that used a different default language change special characters when opened up on a different computer with a different default language?

If the answer to that question is yes, how would I go about fixing this? My main issue is that I am trying to plot cities but the majority of the city names have non-English characters in it (such as fractions or Å) and even after I remove them, I am unable to find them on a map.

Thanks for any assistance!

- Hopelessly Confused Student

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally stumbled upon my own answer while I was writing an email to my professor.

1. Open the Excel Workbook and Save-As a CSV.
2. Open CSV in Notepad.
3. Save-As and change the encoding to UTF-8.
4. Reopen CSV in Excel.

Everything works fine now.